# IP phone behind a firewall on FreeBSD - IPFilter

Tags: firewall, sip, freebsd, squid, nat

I have installed a firewall on FreeBSD 8.2 using ipf+ipnat, also SQUID 2.7 as web proxy

All users can access to internet fine, but my big problem are the IP phones, they try access to sip server on internet (external provider service), they can't establish the connection.

the ports used to sip services are:
SIP: Port 5060-5070 UDP/TCP
RTP (Voice) Traffic: Ports 10000-20000 UDP

This is my current system configuration, there is something wrong, but i don't know what

Interfaces:
rl0 = LAN office 192.168.10.x
bge0 = WAN internet connection

rc.conf:

```
squid_enable="YES"
ipfilter_enable="YES"
ipfilter_rules="/etc/ipf.rules"
ipmon_enable="YES"
ipmon_flags="-Ds"
gateway_enable="YES"
ipnat_enable="YES"
ipnat_rules="/etc/ipnat.rules"
```

ipf.rules:

```
pass out quick on rl0 all
pass in quick on rl0 all

pass out quick on bge0 all
pass in quick on bge0 all

pass in quick on lo0 all
pass out quick on lo0 all
```

I opened all traffic to both interfaces (temporally), but i not got a good result, all ip phones don't work yet

ipnat.rules:

```
rdr rl0 0.0.0.0/0 port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080 tcp # transparent proxy
rdr bge0 0.0.0.0/0 port 22 -> 127.0.0.1 port 22 tcp # ssh server
map bge0 192.168.10.0/16 -> 0.0.0.0/32 proxy port ftp ftp/tcp
map bge0 192.168.10.0/16 -> 0.0.0.0/32 portmap tcp/udp auto
map bge0 192.168.10.0/16 -> 0.0.0.0/32
```

all ip phones and computers has static ip, freebsd server as gateway and a valid DNS server.

Answer (score 2):

SIP phones behind NAT need an STUN server to work.

(Either use the one provided by your sip provider, or try net/stund from port collection)

If you have only one phone, you might also try portforwarding:

```
#SIP
#rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to $ext_addr port = 5060 -> \
    $IP_PHONE port 5060
#RTP
#rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to $ext_addr port = 5004 -> \
#        $IP_PHONE port 5004
#stun
#rdr pass on $ext_if proto tcp from any to $ext_addr port = 10000 -> \
 #        $IP_PHONE port 10000
```

Comment: That's close enough to the truth (needing STUN) for a +1: using ICE kinda-sorta implies using STUN. You can also build a SIP client that can be administratively configured to use external IPs for certain address ranges!

Answer (score 1):

Your first option should be SIP Express Router, or SER.  [The website](http://www.iptel.org/ser/) would be an excellent place to start.  Failing that (you can't install it for some reason), you'll probably have to go old-school.

The problem you are likely running into is that incoming connections to the phone are coming from outside the network, so there is no port "saved" for the incoming traffic.  You can overcome some of this by registering regularly, or you can set up your firewall and NAT configurations to pass traffic from your provider to a specific phone, but that leaves you with just one phone making the connection.  You'll need to configure your upstream provider to send each phone's connections via a different port and tie that port to a specific IP and port.  For example:

```
rdr rtk0 123.123.123.123/32 port 5061 -> 192.168.100.11 port 5061 udp
rdr rtk0 123.123.123.123/32 port 5062 -> 192.168.100.12 port 5062 udp
etc.
```

where 123.123.123.123 is your provider's SIP host address.  Configure your phones so that they communicate on port 5060 + some offset as well.

Even if that helps you with your connections, you may still run into RTP problems.  STUN will help that somewhat, but you may need to limit your SIP phones so that their RTP ports are unique (so that traffic from one phone doesn't suddenly start showing up on another).  The port ranges for SIP and RTP are ridiculously huge - you can limit your phones to, say, 10 per phone and cover a lot of ground with very little trouble.  That would look something like this:

```
rdr rtk0 123.123.123.123/32 port 10000-10009 -> 192.168.100.11 port 10000 udp
rdr rtk0 123.123.123.123/32 port 10010-10019 -> 192.168.100.12 port 10010 udp
```

Set your phone RTP ranges to their unique ranges and you should be relatively good to go.

Note that using the SIP Server's address in the RDR makes this far less risky than a blanket 0.0.0.0/0 address redirect would.